# Applying an extrusion to multiple layer from a python script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to apply a Base Height extrusion that's 10 feet in height to all  layers in my ArcGIS Pro map document using a python script.  Per [ESRI's documentation on extrusion](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm), the syntax should be `extrusion ({extrusion_type}, {expression})` .

Below is the code that I'm trying to use. It's not that graceful as I'm still trying to learn python:

```
import arcpy

# Variables to form defintion query
field = 'SUBCODE'
value = "(1152,1153,1154,1155)"

# concatenate query syntax
queryStr = str(field) + '"IN"' + str(value)

# Specify the aprx project (CURRENT), dataframe (Layers)
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps("Map_3D")[0]

# Apply defintion query to specified layer group
for lyr in m.listLayers("CONDO*"):
if lyr.supports("DEFINITIONQUERY"):
   lyr.definitionQuery = queryStr

# Make copy of selected features
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("CONDO_1ST","CONDO_1ST_LEVEL")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("CONDO_2ND","CONDO_2ND_LEVEL")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("CONDO_3RD","CONDO_3RD_LEVEL")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("CONDO_4TH","CONDO_4TH_LEVEL")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("CONDO_5TH","CONDO_5TH_LEVEL")

# Layer 3D To FeatureClass
arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d("CONDO_1ST_LEVEL",'CONDO_1ST_LEVEL_3D')
arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d("CONDO_2ND_LEVEL",'CONDO_2ND_LEVEL_3D')
arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d("CONDO_3RD_LEVEL",'CONDO_3RD_LEVEL_3D')
arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d("CONDO_4TH_LEVEL",'CONDO_4TH_LEVEL_3D')
arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d("CONDO_5TH_LEVEL",'CONDO_5TH_LEVEL_3D')

# Apply extrusion
for lyr in m.listLayers("CONDO*"):
if lyr.supports("EXTRUSION"):
   lyr.extrusion('BASE_HEIGHT',10)
```

I'm not receiving any error when I run the script nor is it making updates to the layers.

Comment: Can you expand your code snippet so we can see more of what you've defined above `for lyr in m.listLayers()`?  What/where is `m`?

Comment: Thanks Midavalo for your reply.  I've made edits to my original question so that you can see the entire code.

Comment: I figured it out - I forgot to apply the Geoprocessing tool "Layer 3D To Feature Class".  Thanks again for reaching out to help Midavalo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the Geoprocessing tool "Layer 3D To Feature Class" in order to have the extrusion work.  Here's a copy of the syntax I used:

```
 arcpy.Layer3DToFeatureClass_3d(input, output)
```

Comment: updated my code to show where I applied the "Layer 3D To Feature Class"